# Run 2 repeating async functions without pausing the other on await

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, async-await, mean

so I am trying to run 2 repeating functions which both use async. Both functions at some point use the async await feature. The problem is when one function uses await it pauses both functions. How would I stop this from happening so when one function uses await the other function doesn't pause. Thanks. Example below.

```
const collectInfo = async () => {
    return new Promise(async function(resolve, reject) {
        // Collect info from the database then
        resolve(data);
    });
}
const functionOne = async () => {
    timeLeft = 5000;

    var timerOne = setInterval(async function(){
        if(timeLeft === 0){
            var getInfTwo = await collectInfo();
            console.log(getInfOne);
            startFunctionOne();
            clearInterval(timerOne);
        }
        timeLeft--;
    },  10);
}
const functioTwo = async () => {
    timeLeft = 10000;

    var timerTwo = setInterval(async function(){
        if(timeLeft === 0){
            var getInfOne = await collectInfo();
            console.log(getInfOne);
            startFunctionTwo();
            clearInterval(timerTwo);
        }
        timeLeft--;
    },  10);
}

const startFunctionOne = async () => {
    functionOne();
}
const startFunctioTwo = async () => {
    functioTwo();
}

startFunctionOne();
startFunctioTwo();
```

Answer (score 0):

Be carefull, as you haven't us the keyword var or let in functionOne and functionTwo for variable timeLeft, this variable become global, so you use the same global variable in the two functions.

You can't choose when "pause" the function, its automatically done with async, if your two functions are launched in same times and are waiting an input/ouput there's nothing to do.

Answer (score 0):

You need to group these statements in an async function. This way we get two async functions, `startFunctionOne()` and `startFunctionTwo()`

Now we take advantage of the event loop to run these async non-blocking functions concurrently.

```
const functionOnePromise = startFunctionOne()
const functionTwoPromise = startFunctionTwo()

await functionOnePromise
await functionTwoPromise
```

We have grouped the statements into two functions. Inside the function, each statement depends on the execution of the previous one. Then we concurrently execute both the functions `startFunctionOne()` and `startFunctionTwo()`